# Внезапная конкуренция в EntityFrameworkCore + MySql (Pomelo)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Приветсвую!Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой,но вопроса по теме тут не нашел(хотя плохо исал) Гугл кидает на гитхуб где данная ошибка рассматривалась в случае с обновлением записи. В моем случае оно возникает при ее добавлении. Задаю вопрос до того как пойму гайд на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)  (он тоже как я понял из кода про обновление записи) на который указывает экзепшн, т.к. в любом случае прийду сюда если ничего не выйдет...

...ну а теперь больше по делу:
[image: скрин]

```
Возникло исключение: CLR/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException
An exception of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'
```

Orders.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KupcheAspNetCore
{
    public partial class Orders
    {
        public Orders()
        {
            Orderfiles = new HashSet<Orderfiles>();
            Orderimages = new HashSet<Orderimages>();
        }

        public int IdOrders { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Geomap { get; set; }
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
        public int? Viewers { get; set; }
        public int UsersId { get; set; }
        public sbyte? ThereImages { get; set; }
        public sbyte? ThereFiles { get; set; }
        public sbyte? IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AdditionTime { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdate { get; set; }

        public Users Users { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Orderfiles> Orderfiles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Orderimages> Orderimages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Coutnry.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KupcheAspNetCore
{
    public partial class Country
    {
        public Country()
        {
            City = new HashSet<City>();
        }

        public int IdCountry { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AdditionTime { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<City> City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ordersController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using KupcheAspNetCore.Models;

namespace  KupcheAspNetCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OrdersController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostOrders([FromBody]Orders order)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Country neworder = new Country();
                neworder.Name = "caption";
                neworder.ShortName = "texttextextext";
                // neworder.Cost = 6;
                // neworder.UsersId = 1;
                
                using(servicedbContext db = new servicedbContext()){
                    db.Country.Add(neworder);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Post response order: "+ neworder.Name.ToString());
                    return Ok(neworder);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Пробовал брать более простую таблица(видно на скрине).
Возможно ли так же что это как-то касается MySQL конкретно?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: думаю стоит залогировать запросы к БД и выяснить почему rowsAffected = 0

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью логгера или есть встроеные в EF методы?

Comment: погуглите, есть способы для EF, пакет для внешнего логгера, на крайник случай можно в конфигах mysql включить, чтобы все запросы сохранял.

Comment: Благодарю! Посмотрел на запросы, почему-то сгенерированный контекст проставил запрет на генерацию Id(автоинкремент) решилось заменой  
`entity.Property(e => e.IdActivityTypes)
                    .HasColumnName("idActivityTypes")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();`  
На   
`entity.Property(e => e.IdActivityTypes)
                    .HasColumnName("idActivityTypes")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю! Посмотрел на запросы, почему-то сгенерированный контекст проставил запрет на генерацию Id(автоинкремент) решилось заменой
`entity.Property(e => e.IdActivityTypes)
                    .HasColumnName("idActivityTypes")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();`
На
`entity.Property(e => e.IdActivityTypes)
                    .HasColumnName("idActivityTypes")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`